# Cherrypy dispatcher with popagrs decorator. Child node routes

Tags: server, url-routing, cherrypy, dispatcher

I am trying to get the following urls to respond

1. /book/[bookname] (working)
2. /book/getdetails/[bookname] (working)
3. /book/[bookname]/page/[pagenumber] (working)
4. /book/[bookname]/page/getdetails/[pagenumber] **(not working)**
5. /book/[bookname]/page/test (working)

Basic Service handler:

```
class Service(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.book = Book()

    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        return 'normal page'
```

Books Class:

```
@cherrypy.popargs('book_name')
class Book(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.page = Page()

    @cherrypy.expose
    @cherrypy.tools.json_out()
    def index(self, book_name):
        return {"book name": book_name}

    @cherrypy.expose
    @cherrypy.tools.json_out()
    def getdetails(self, book_name):
        return {"details": bookname}
```

Page Class:

```
@cherrypy.popargs('page_number')
class Page(object):

    @cherrypy.expose
    @cherrypy.tools.json_out()
    def index(self, book_name, page_number):
        return {"book": book_name, "no": page_number}

    # DOES NOT WORK AS EXPEXTED
    # @cherrypy.expose
    # @cherrypy.tools.json_out()
    # def getdetails(self, book_name, page_number):
    #     return {"book": book_name, "no": page_number}

    @cherrypy.expose
    @cherrypy.tools.json_out()
    def test(self, book_name):
        return {"details": "some test"}
```

Service is the root class

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    cherrypy.quickstart(Service())
```

`

Comment: after brute forcing, I came across the following solution:
**/book/[bookname]/page/[pagenumber]/getdetails (works)**

I know it is not the exact solution but it satisfies my requirement

Comment: You may want to use routes dispatcher as well

Comment: `popargs` only retrieves first slug off the path: https://github.com/cherrypy/cherrypy/blob/master/cherrypy/_helper.py#L172